# What happens to command line arguments once printf() is used on them?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

So I've written this small program, and I'm a newbie. It prints out the command line arguments I give it. I just don't understand why it worked before I changed the i variable to be initialized to one, yet when I changed it I get a segmentation fault.

The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

    if ( argc > 1) {
        printf( "Filename: %s has %d arguments.",  argv[0], argc );
    } else  {
        printf ("No arguments found!");
        getchar();  
        return 0;
    }

    int i = 1;
    printf( "The arguments are: \n" );
    for ( i < argc; ++i;) {
        printf( "Argument %d is: %s \n", i, argv[i] );
    } 

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I've never seen anything which says something happens to the command line arguments once they have been used. However my hypothesis is something happened to the command line arguments after I used printf() on them. It worked the first time when the counter variable i was initialized to zero. When I retooled the program to skip the zero-eth by initializing i to one the argument gave me that segmentation fault. I did this because I was a bit confused about what was happening. It wasn't printing out the filename a second time like I thought it would yet I changed it so it wouldn't anyway (makes a lot of sense huh? Not in retrospect lol).

Comment: You've written the test in the 'initialization' part of the for loop; you've got your increment acting as a test (so the loop is going to run until `i` is incremented to zero, which is going to take a long time (or crash your program as you access invalid memory); and then the reinitialization clause is empty.  You need `for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)`, more or less as Nirk says.

Comment: Where's the required "minimal understanding" when one doesn't even know the **syntax?**

Comment: @H2CO3: the syntax is correct (as in permissible and compilable).  It is the semantics of the syntax that is wrong.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Indeed. I meant that. Still missing the "minimal understanding".

Comment: Beginners mistake; easily made.  Hands up if you've never made any vaguely similar mistake...  One of the more interesting problems (back in the days before there was standard C, so no prototypes) was a program that started `int main(char **argv, int argc)`.  Once you spot it, it is trivial — but there's `argc` and `argv`.  Granted, that was a student in the class I was teaching, but it took me a minute or two to spot the issue.

Comment: That's real nice H2CO3. That is C90 code. GCC doesn't fully support C99 yet so I used C90. I do know the exact syntax. As far as I can tell the book I'm reading uses C99 but GCC does not support it completely. I do not know everything about C. The compiler complained that intializations were not allowed in the for...next loop. So I left it out.

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop is broken:

```
for(;i<argc;++i)
```

The first block is the initial condition and the second block is the check performed before each iteration. As you wrote it, the check was ++i which would be true even after the last argument.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use the for...next loop is like so (for C 1990/1989):

```
   int i;
   printf( "The arguments are: \n" );
   for ( i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
```

Many people were complaining about my lack of knowledge about the syntax. I do know how to write a for...next loop. I've written many in C++ and C is almost no different. I followed the compilers warnings and adjusted but did not really think about what I was doing or check for anyone else with the same problem.

Because the compiler I am using GCC does not completely support C99 and I chose to stick with C90 as my compiling option. I am just learning C and I've found it a lot like C++ (fancy that) but I do not claim to know everything about C, or its previous versions.

Answer (score -1):

if you're working with C you should first initialize declare and initialize i and do you if statement your program works fine if you change the placement of int i = 1

Comment: Not my down-vote, but because C99 and C11 both permit `int i = 1;` where it is written.  Only archaic compilers that only support C89 (such as MSVC) do not support the declaration of `i` where it is written.

Comment: I don't see how the program would work fine if he move the `int i = 1;` to somewhere where it was permitted by C89

Comment: it work fine and didn't crash on VS2010, I have to say that  I didn't give a parameter !!